# getActiveSession gives null on Activity start although logged in to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to implement a logic where the Activity starts normal when the user has already an opened session in Facebook. When the user is not logged in he is forwarded to a LoginActivity.

However I couldn't find any approach yet that works fine.

When I use the getActiveSession() method in the onCreate() it's always giving null on first start of the Activity even though I am logged in to Facebook. The result is that I am forwarded to the LoginActivity where the uiHelper then fires the callBack that the session is opened.
I also tried to get session from cache and everything else that is on the web regarding the session==null.

Is there any other way to get not null on first activity start? Or to save the current session somewhere when activity is destroyed to restore it afterwards?

My second approach was to use the uiHelper on MainActivity start to see if the user is logged in or not. However it doesn't fire the callback if the session is closed or not opened on Activity start...

I hope anybody has an idea how to solve this or knows a different approach.
Thank you very much for any help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call Session.openActiveSession() before calling the Session.getSession() method

Comment: you are right that gives the session on first activity start. thank you very much!